# Would non-neural physiological insights be considered to be in the field of neuroscience?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology

For example, would e.g. SCR (skin conductance response) or hormone level be considered to be "neuroscientific measures" according to general definition of neuroscience?

Comment: What is SCR? It's best practice to limit the use of acronyms in questions, or at least explain them. Regarding the question - have you done some research yourself? What did you find? Adding your findings may also specify the question. Are you specifically interested in hormones? I'm asking because *'non-neural physiological insights'* is very vague.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's in the field of neuroscience or not? These are just labels.

Comment: I want to know the scope of neuroscience for a literature review.

Comment: The best part of writing a literature review is that you get to choose the scope.

Comment: I know that. But I still want to know what is the "usual" definition.

Answer (score 2):

There is increasing scientific evidence to incorporate other organ systems when considering the whole function of the nervous system. Neuroendocrinology, neurogastroenterology, and neuroimmunology are burgeoning fields of research.

If for instance, you were interested in the effects of stress on neurodevelopment, you would likely want to be measuring cortisol levels in your animal model.

If you were performing a study on human fear response, you might want to record SCR in addition to other measures (EEG, fMRI, etc.).

The definition of neuroscience is intentionally broad. There are many biochemists, for instance, who are interested primarily in cell structure, stability, and the transport mechanisms within who study neural tissue specifically because neurons happen to be interesting cases (axons can be very long, how do nutrients and proteins get to where they need to be?).

--

Clin Psychopharmacol Neurosci 2013; 11(3): 107-117  https://doi.org/10.9758/cpn.2013.11.3.107

Ann Clin Biochem. 2017 May;54(3):308-322. doi: 10.1177/0004563216687335. Epub 2017 Mar 16

J Del Signore, Steven & Rodal, Avital. (2016). The membrane strikes back: phosphoinositide binding regulates Skywalker function. Nature Structural & Molecular Biology. 23. 956-957. 10.1038/nsmb.3313.

J. Herzog, Josiah & Deshpande, Mugdha & Shapiro, Leah & Rodal, Avital & Paradis, Suzanne. (2017). TDP-43 misexpression causes defects in dendritic growth. Scientific Reports. 7. 10.1038/s41598-017-15914-4.